# Could "cookbook" mean "usual"?

Tags: meaning, nouns, ambiguity, disambiguation

I am reading the following article:

> Nelson, T., Maxfield, S., & Kolb, D. (2009). Women entrepreneurs and
>   venture capital: Managing the shadow negotiation. International
>   Journal of Gender and Entrepreneurship, 1(1), 57–76.
>   https://doi.org/10.1108/17566260910942345

On page 65 there is written:

> Kelley went to a woman friend whose business was also in the life
>   sciences to get advice on potential investors with interest and
>   successful experiences in the same industry arena. The friend helped
>   Kelley with an introduction but the investor “wasn’t interested in
>   this ‘anomaly’ business;” he wanted the “cookbook.”
>   Rebecca, meeting initial resistance, eventually screened VC firm
>   portfolios for women-led businesses believing that this signaled an
>   openness to “non-cookbook” opportunities.

What's the meaning of the word "cookbook" in this context? I think it would mean "usual", but I am unable to find this meaning or a similar meaning for the word "cookbook" in dictionaries.

Comment: I've never heard the expression but it probably means he wanted the recipe: step-by-step instructions; the precise method. But I don't understand *this 'anomaly' business*, so I could be wrong.

Comment: It's jargon for standard or "tried and true"

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I think "anomaly" business refers to the fact that women's businesses are "anomalous", in the sense that they tend to appeal to different market niches that what Venture Capitalists are used to

Comment: @Conrado can you translate it like "the grandmother's recipe"?

Comment: @rtrtrt Oh OK, thanks. Never heard it.

Comment: @rtrtrt I _think_ that's the connotation. You hope to have as high a probability as possible of success by doing it the way it's always been done.

Comment: @Conrado do you have some references for that?

Comment: @rtrtrt https://www.greenbiz.com/article/21st-century-business-cookbook-offers-success-strategy

Comment: And in the tech literature: https://archive.org/details/TransistorCookbook/mode/2up

Comment: Ah, but now I see those are actual books. You asked about the procedure itself. I'll improve that a little later.

Comment: In this use, cookbook means standardized, like *boilerplate*. Not specifically a recipe, procedure, or formula, but formulaic to the extent it's *textbook*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's jargon for standard or "tried and true".

From [Mirriam-Webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cookbook):

> **cookbook** adjective
>
> Definition of cookbook (Entry 2 of 2) : involving or using step-by-step procedures whose rationale is usually not explained
>
> //a cookbook approach

The sort of cookbook method the first investor is supposed to have wanted is described as analogous to a certain, apparently rather dull if functional, cookbook (from [serc.carleton.edu/eet/cookbooks.html](https://serc.carleton.edu/eet/cookbooks.html):

> This cookbook is very straightforward and prescriptive: the
>   ingredients, procedures, and expected outcome for each dish are well
>   defined. Though someone using this cookbook could prepare the specific
>   dishes in the book, they wouldn't learn any alternative preparations
>   or information about the ingredients. This is not the type of cookbook
>   that the EET is modeled after...

Further down on the same page, a more artistic and educational cookbook is described:

> This cookbook offers specific recipes, but it also provides
>   opportunities to learn about ingredients and cooking techniques along
>   the way. The book's "About" sections offer valuable advice on choosing
>   and using ingredients, and recipes have suggestions for customizing
>   dishes or making alternate presentations...

Sometimes the term carries negative implications, as in the title of this (quite ethereal) essay:
[Why No “Cookbook” Approach? Jung on Dream-work](https://jungiancenter.org/why-no-cookbook-approach-jung-on-dream-work/)

Sometimes it means, as Old Brixtonian said, "the recipe: step-by-step instructions; the precise method.", with a connotation of *failproof*, or at least *low risk*. Here is an example in a math book (*[A First Course in Optimization Theory](https://books.google.cl/books?id=yAfug81P-8YC&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=cookbook%20procedure&source=bl&ots=_JYP253bNK&sig)*):
[image: clipping from *A F C i O T*]

In these last two examples, "cookbook" is an adjective, as is the second instance in your clipping ("non-cookbook opportunities").

Comment: +1 to repair the damage caused by a drive-by downvoter.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, Yosef Baskin got it right in his comment:

> In this use, cookbook means standardized, like boilerplate. Not
>   specifically a recipe, procedure, or formula, but formulaic to the
>   extent it's textbook.

"Cookbook" is often used in programming, eg, to mean a technique or formula that is out of a textbook or otherwise largely standardized.  And sometimes it's used in a somewhat derogatory sense to imply that the technique was copied without customizing it appropriately to the current context.